# Is shareholder influence and feedback mostly limited to shareholder meetings?

Tags: shareholder-meeting

Seeing videos of shareholder meetings of larger corporations, it seems that the board gives its presentations, a few representatives of mostly larger shareholders (like banks) may ask them a one or two questions and then there may be votes and the management is discharged and voted in for the next year.

Is shareholder influence and the excercise of their right to information and voting limited to this short event once a year?

Or could they request information from a company and maybe do things like oust the existing board between meetings if they do something unacceptable? Is there a continuous line of feedback between a company and its stakeholders? Or is the board left to its own devices most of the time?

Comment: If you own enough shares you can insist on being on the board or appointing someone of your choice to the board to represent you. If you own > 50% of the shares you can replace the board whenever you wish.

Comment: This depends on local laws and the corporate bylaws, but generally speaking shareholders affect the company through their voting power which is usually exercised at the shareholder's meeting.